# Improving readability and functionality of a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, maps, definition

I have the following definition:

```
def heat( number ):

if number == "r":
    h = 12
elif number == "b":
    h = 24

return h
```

However, I would like to make it look nicer and not have to reply on if statements. I have been told I can do it in the following way (I WANT to do it this way, so if I can receive help just on this particular example please):

```
def heat(number):
    m = { "r" : 12,
          "b" : 24 }
try:
    return m[number]
except KeyError:
    return 0.0
```

I however don't understand how that will return a value for 'h', which is what I want. Could someone please explain this method to me? Also I get confused between, maps and dictionnaires etc. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I get the above example but what if I have two inputs to the function?

e.g.

```
def heat( temp, coeff )
```

do I write for the return:

```
return m(heat, coeff)
```

Or does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also could use a single statement (if you only have this limited options):

```
def heat(number):
    return 12 if number == "r" else (24 if number == "b" else 0.0)
```

However if you need more than 2 alternatives, the dictionary as you proposed is better.

You also could avoid the exception:

```
def heat(number):
    m = { "r" : 12,
          "b" : 24 }

    return m[number] if number in m else 0.0
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I apparently have to keep the exception in and am trying to avoid any if statements if possible. I still don't understand how that returns the value for 'h' if it's not used in the function?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid any if statement? (the try/except mechanism also internally can be seen as an if statement). I'm afraid I don't understand your last remark. You also are not using h in your second example where my second part of the answer is based on.

Comment: It was a task I was given to do. Sorry I may have sounded a bit confused but I've figured out what my problem was..I'm still fairly new to Python. Thanks for your help =)

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary variant can be written a bit more concisely:

```
def heat(number):
    return {'r':12,'b':24}.get(number,0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

***maps*** and *dictionaries*

Generally speaking, *maps* and *dictionaries* are two words that mean the same thing.  They're used interchangeably in a lot of literature and by a lot of people.

*maps* are called that because that's what they do.  They're a collection of pairs of arbitrary values mapped to each other.  Given one of the values in the pair (the one known as the *key*), the other (the *value*) can be obtained relatively effiently.  Aside from their ease of use, *maps* are usually used for this effiency purpose.  (In your example, both "r" and "b" are *keys*, and 12 and 24 are their respective *values*.)

Strictly speaking, the standard data structure that implements this in Python is known as a `dict` (short for *dictionary*) and the word they use in the documentation to describe the concept is *mapping* object.[1](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

In order to understand how you're able to *return a value for 'h'*, you should [read up on how `dicts` are used](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping), because that's what `m` is.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's helped me understand things a bit better =)